# How do I link my google user with aws cognito's user pool without knowing the user's google's SUB

Tags: aws-lambda, google-oauth, amazon-cognito

I want to provision users to my user-pool and allow them to use either username+password OR google's SSO so long as the email match. when using `adminLinkProviderForUser` to link them I need to provide the users's google's SUB that I don't know in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, I hope that helps anyone. If someone has a better solution, please let me know:

In my pre-signup Lambda I extract Google's SUB and email, look for the user and link them with `AdminLinkProviderForUser` once the like is done I return `MARGED_GOOGLE` string in the error. The error string is sent in the callback url to the browser where I identify the `MARGED_GOOGLE` string and tell the user that we just finished to marge his account and he needs to relogin. next time he login the link is there and there is no signup.

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  if (event.triggerSource === "PreSignUp_ExternalProvider") {
    if (event.userName.startsWith("Google_")) {
      AWS.config.update({ region: "us-east-2" });
      const COGNITO_CLIENT = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({
        apiVersion: "2016-04-18",
        region: "us-east-2"
      });

      const  adminGetUserParams = {
        UserPoolId: "<UserPoolId>" /* required */,
        Username: event.request.userAttributes.email /* required */
      };
      COGNITO_CLIENT.adminGetUser(adminGetUserParams, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
          callback("no signed in", null);
        } else {
          // successful response
          const params = {
            DestinationUser: {
              /* required */
              ProviderAttributeValue: data.Username,
              ProviderName: "Cognito"
            },
            SourceUser: {
              /* required */
              ProviderAttributeName: "Cognito_Subject",
              ProviderAttributeValue: event.userName.substr(7),
              ProviderName: "Google"
            },
            UserPoolId: "<UserPoolId>" /* required */
          };
          COGNITO_CLIENT.adminLinkProviderForUser(params, (e, d) => {
            if (e) callback("no signed in", null);
            else {
              callback("MARGED_GOOGLE", null);
            }
          });
        }
      });
    } else {
      callback("no signed in", null);
    }
  } else {
    callback(null, event);
  }
};
```